# jqGrid select text in active cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Problem is: using jqGrid One cant select text in cell when grid has **cellEdit:true**
As soon as I release mouse button selection resets -_-
User needs to be able to select text in cell and then copy it.

has anyone come across this? what could be the best way to deal with this very annoying issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more thinking managed to overcome this issue by suppressing click on cell

```
loadComplete:function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('td').not('.td_which_should_have_onClick').unbind("click");
        $('.edit-cell').bind('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

},
```